# Removing running head on otherpages in apa6 man

Tags: fancyhdr, templates, apa6

I know I shouldn't be using the apa6 manuscript template for my thesis, but I just didn't got anything else to look this good. Anyway, I want to remove the running head on all pages. I already succeeded with the title page, but not the other pages. Also, I do want to keep the page numbering. This is what I used to remove the running head on the title page, but for some reason {otherpage} does not do anything.

```
\fancypagestyle{titlepage}{%
    \lhead{\MakeUppercase{}}%
    \rhead{\thepage}%
}
\fancypagestyle{otherpage}{%
    \lhead{\MakeUppercase{empty}}%
    \rhead{\thepage}%
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Instead of posting code fragments, you'll get help faster if you post a small compilable document that shows what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APA6 sets the default pagestyle to `otherpage` inside the class, so when you change the pagestyle you need issue a new `\pagestyle{otherpage}` after your redefinition to override the original one. The reason the title page definition worked is that the pagestyle is set when you issue the `\maketitle` command, and so the new definition works.

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6}
\shorttitle{Title}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\fancypagestyle{titlepage}{%
    \lhead{}%
    \rhead{\thepage}%
}
\fancypagestyle{otherpage}{%
    \lhead{}%
    \rhead{\thepage}%
}
\pagestyle{otherpage}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're awesome, it worked. Thank you!